# How to add indexes to FOSUserBundle:User?

Tags: mongodb, symfony, doctrine, symfony-2.1, fosuserbundle

I noticed FOSUserBundle does not create any indexes.

We are supposed to create a user Document like this:

```
use FOS\UserBundle\Document\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations as MongoDB;

/**
 * @MongoDB\Document
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @MongoDB\Id(strategy="auto")
     */
    protected $id;

    /*
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        // your own logic
    }
    */

}
```

So how do I add an index to say, the 'email' field? Should I just overwrite the inherited attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually FOSUserBundle does create. You should run

> php app\console doctrine:mongodb:schema:update

to create them. By default there is usernameCanonical and emailCanonical indexes.

If you need custom index use [this approach](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/latest/reference/indexes.html):

```
<?php
/**
 * @MongoDB\Document
 * @MongoDB\Indexes({
 *   @MongoDB\Index(keys={"email"="asc"})
 * })
 */
class User extends BaseUser {
  // ...
```

and do not forget to run *doctirne:mongodb:schema:update* task again.

Comment: I was using `doctrine:mongodb:schema:create --index`. Your solution worked: `php app\console doctrine:mongodb:schema:update`.